# Find convergence domain of integral

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence

I need to find convergence domain of $$\int_1^2 \! \frac{\ln(x-1)}{(4-x^2)^p} \, \mathrm{d}x$$

I've tried to use estimates like $\frac{\ln(x-1)}{(4-x^2)^p} < \frac{1}{(4-x^2)^p}$ and change of variable $t = 4-x^2$, but it didn't help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints: You have possible problems at $1$ and $2.$ At $1,$ the denominator stays calm but the numerator $\to -\infty.$ But it's only a logarithmic blowup, so that should be OK. At $2,$ you have the battle of zeros: Verify that $|\ln (x-1)|$ is on the order of $|x-2|$ there. Downstairs, just factor $4-x^2$ to see what to do.